# Why do we use a custom type instead string?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am reading a book about typescript. In one chapter I have found example of code:

```
type OptionsType = {
    db: string;
};

export const connect = ({ db }: OptionsType): void => {
  mongoose.connect(db);
};
```

And using is:

```
const db = "mongodb://";
connect({ db });
```

Why did we wrap `db` string connection to the custom type `OptionsType`? Why dont use string `db`, because `mongoose.connect(db);` accepts this.

Comment: It's hard to answer definitively why some example code did a certain thing.  Do you want guesses?  My guess is that they're trying to show you how destructuring works.  Or maybe they want to allow the `OptionsType` to have more properties than just the `db` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `connect` is defined by the book author. He decided it should take a single parameter that is an object with a property named `db`.

He implemented that function so that it takes the value out of the property named `db` of function argument and uses it to call `mongoose.connect` which requires its first parameter to be connection string.

There was no particular reason why the author decided to define his function like that. Maybe he wanted to illustrate how you can pass values into the function as properties of an object?

Since he's passing just a single value there was really no reason to wrap in in an object.

Comment: So, why he passed it `connect({ db });` instead: `connect({ db: db });`

Comment: Also why we again wrap it to object here: `({ db }: OptionsType): => {}` ?

Comment: @Jony Yes `connect({ db });` is just a shorthand notation for `connect({ db: db });` and we have `({ db }: OptionsType) => {}` to take the value out of property named `db` of object of type `OptionsType` and into the local variable named `db`. We could have `(param: OptionsType) => { var db = param.db; }` instead.